# Very strange behavior when I try to connect using SSH. Why it works only if I copy and paste the IP address?

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, ip, telnet

I am experiencing a very strange behavior.

The situation is the following one: I connect to my **RaspBerry Pi** from my **Ubuntu Linux 12.04** using **SSH**

So I do the following operation: I go into my router web page (at the address 192.168.1.1), I go into the **DHCP Cleint** section and here I found that to my **RaspBerry Pi** is assigned the following ip address **192.168.1.4**, so in the bash I perform the following command:

```
andrea@andrea-virtual-machine:~$ sudo ssh miner@192.168.1.4
[sudo] password for andrea: 
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.4 port 22: No route to host
```

and how you can see it fail because it can't found a route.

Ok...the very strange thing is that if I perform it again this operation **COPYING** and **PASTING** the SAME ip address from the router administration page to my shell, it work

```
andrea@andrea-virtual-machine:~$ sudo ssh miner@192.168.1.4
miner@192.168.1.4's password: 
Linux raspberrypi 3.12.20+ #687 PREEMPT Fri May 30 16:39:11 BST 2014 armv6l

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
Last login: Fri Jun 13 20:39:18 2014 from 192.168.1.5
miner@raspberrypi ~ $
```

How is it possible? Why? How can I fix this issue?

Tnx

Comment: you typed the first one and copied the second?

Comment: yes. I typed the first one (when it fail) and copy&paste the second one (when it work fine)

Comment: can you paste the router administration ip address to text file then here, i am wondering if the copy is picking up additional details that are hidden

Comment: Do you mean the ip address that I insert in the borwser to access to my router administration panel or what else?
So in the first case it is: http://192.168.1.1/login.cgi

Comment: no highlight the raspberry pi ip address in the router administration, then copy it and paste it here and to text file liek gedit

Comment: Ok, so I selected the ip address of raspberry into my router administration page, I copyed and I past here: 192.168.1.4
It seems to me that there is no other relevant informations

Comment: nope there aint, there was possibility that it might have had extra information, at the moment i cant think of why if i do ill let oyu know

Comment: I'm wondering if (rather than copy/paste) that there is a mechanism on the SSH server (your Pi) that you've turned on that's denying the connection but (for some reason) it then checks again and finds your IP on an allow list. No idea why il this would ever happen but I don't think the fact you're copy/pasting the IP afterwards is the deciding factor in whether it will connect successfully...